# Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server issue

Tags: nginx, proxy, fedora

First time I'm stalling nginx server in my fedora 24. I'm using apache server for development. For onlyoffice integration I have to install nginx server. I installed nginx server by using this command `dnf install nginx`

Before starting nginx server I stopped apache and disabled it also like below.

```
systemctl stop httpd
systemctl disable httpd
```

If I start the nginx server `sudo service nginx start` I'm getting below error.

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  nginx.service
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So I ran the `systemctl status nginx.service` command to know issue detail, I got below output in my terminal.

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl -l status nginx.service
● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-10-20 01:45:57 IST; 10s ago
  Process: 10719 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 10709 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 20 01:45:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Oct 20 01:45:57 localhost.localdomain nginx[10719]: nginx: [emerg] no port in upstream "php-fpm" in /etc/nginx/default.d/phpMyAdmin.conf:17
Oct 20 01:45:57 localhost.localdomain nginx[10719]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Oct 20 01:45:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 20 01:45:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Oct 20 01:45:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 20 01:45:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I tried several ways to fix by changing the `listen 80` to `listen 801` in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf but no issue. I followed the below urls also but I can't fix the issue.

[nginx not started and can't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868976/nginx-not-started-and-cant-start)

https://serverfault.com/questions/717752/cant-start-nginx-code-exited-status-1-failure

**/etc/nginx/default.d/phpMyAdmin.conf**

```
# phpMyAdmin

location = /phpMyAdmin {
    alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/;
}

location /phpMyAdmin/ {
     root /usr/share;
     index index.php index.html;

     location ~ ^/phpMyAdmin/(.+\.php)$
     {
         try_files $uri =404;
         fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
         include        fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;  //this is line number 17
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know enough about this particular issue to help further, but note that the log output points you towards a specific problem to investigate: `Oct 20 01:45:57 localhost.localdomain nginx[10719]: nginx: [emerg] no port in upstream "php-fpm" in /etc/nginx/default.d/phpMyAdmin.conf:17`

Comment: @mattdm Thanks for your response. I checked that file but I'm not getting. So I added that file content with my question. Please check

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it was because port 80 has been taken.

```
sudo lsof -t -i:80
sudo kill [port in reply]
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue, I had a different situation, I am sure port 80 isn't taken in my machine after I run this command: `netstat -nplt`.

After I **closed Selinux service**, the problem was resolved.

Temporarily close the Selinux service you should run the command below:

```
setenforce 0
```

Permanently disable this service:

```
vim /etc/selinux/config

Change item from `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=disabled`
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for my question as @mattdm suggested, I installed php-fpm and now it's started working.

```
sudo dnf install php-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed php-fpm, you should look for where the socket is running and alter this line `fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;  //this is line number 17`.

You should be able to find it in the `listen` line within the php-fpm pool's config file. E.g. in Ubuntu, you can find it at `/etc/php/<version>/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.

You might be able to get clues on the config with:
`ps aux | grep php-fpm`.