# nginx won't restart, apache2 starts running now and then (automatically)

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx

I have a VPS running my nodeJS app, with Nginx as reverse proxy. The VPS has installed as default Apache. Often my app stops working, i check my vps through ssh and i try to restart nginx:

```js
service nginx restart
```

But i got the error:

> Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Looking for a solution in Stack Overflow i found this post: [Nginx: Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868976/nginx-job-for-nginx-service-failed-because-the-control-process-exited/58332311) where an answer says that i need to stop apache, so i write in console:

```js
sudo killall apache2
service nginx restart
```

And then works fine!! But for some reason apache2 starts running on its own now and then. Is there a way to fix this?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run the commands the error suggested? The output of those is often helpful in solving such issues.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you needs to disable the apache2 service and enable the nginx service.

```
systemctl stop apache2
systemctl disable apache2

systemctl enable nginx
systemctl start nginx
```