# nginx ws invalid URL prefix

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, wss

First time with `nginx`.
I have a nodejs WebSocket server listening at `ws://service_name:3600`.
I'm using `docker-compose`:

```
version: "2"
services:
   # stuff

   service_name:
      image: imagename
      ports:
        - 3600:3600
      links:
        # stuff
        - proxy

   proxy:
     image: image-from-nginx-with-custom-config
     ports:
       - 80:80
       - 443:443
       - 8443:8443
```

My config:

```
// stuff 

server {
    listen          8443;
    server_name     localhost;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/crt.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/key.pem;

    keepalive_timeout    60;

    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    location / {
        proxy_pass ws://service_name:3600;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

I get `nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` at startup.
So nginx doesn't recognize `ws`, what do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx invalid URL prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992908/nginx-invalid-url-prefix)

Comment: In nginx your still need to use http for your url. `proxy_pass http://service_name:3600;`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've tried doing just that but it doesn't seem to work. I may have something wrong in my configuration then...

Comment: @TarunLalwani It works! thank you, add your answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In nginx you still need to use `http` for protocol in your url and not `ws`.

```
proxy_pass http://service_name:3600;
```

The `ws` and `wss` protocol is required for browser, on server side you add below to handle the websockets over http

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```